# Comparison of web hosting providers

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

My current web host that I've been with for over a decade is jerking me around, and I'm ready to find a new provider.  Holy smokes!  There are so many!  It's overwhelming!

I want to see a comparison of the most popular hosting providers.  I want to compare things like:

- Bandwidth allotment
- Storage limit
- Databases

  - MySQL
  - SQL Server
- ## of Free Domains
- ## of Sites

etc.

Better would be a tool that let's me supply parameters that will narrow down the list.  Ie, only windows with unlimited storage, unlimited bandwidth, free sql server databases and less than $5.00 month.

I've found a couple of sites that do something like this, but not very well.  Is there something like what I'm looking for already on the web?  I don't want to go to dozens of different hosting provider sites and jot down all the stats manually.

Comment: Presumably you picked your current host by these same criteria, and that didn't work out well ;)

Comment: @UpTheCreek - As I mentioned, I picked my current host over 10 years ago.  The game has changed a lot since then.

Comment: read this (http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2344/investigating-and-finding-a-web-host/2368#2368), it does not dircetly answer your question, but it's a way of discriminate among web hosters.

Comment: yes I understand - my point is that picking a host by these kind of numbers is silly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to check [Webhostingtalk](http://www.webhostingtalk.com) forums. Yet though, as I have just said in other answer, seems Hostgator is one of the most respected (you can check in the mentioned forum. Plus see several few other with almost same good fame.)

Answer (score 2):

Yah hostgator is the best for service,support,price and features also..

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you **avoid** [Host Clear](http://www.hostclear.com). I used them for a while and I wish I had done some better research. They provide very limited software on their webservers and many features that are free on other hosting plans (like GoDaddy) cost silly amounts of money each month.

That being said, my current webhosting provider of choice is [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com). They know what they are doing there.

Comment: GoDaddy?  My hosting experience with them a couple of years ago was not good.  Just use them for domains now.

Answer (score 1):

Most of my small customers are hosted with [Total Choice Hosting](http://www.totalchoicehosting.com/).

They have the very best service I have experienced and superb reliability.
The pricing of their small packages is excellent, starting at $55/year.

The price goes up significantly if you have a large number of websites 
since they make you pay per site. Because of that my own collection of
sites moved away from them but I miss the reliability! They do have
reseller packages but those did not match my needs unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [UK Web Solutions Direct](http://ukwebsolutionsdirect.co.uk/) for years and have never had any problems. They are reliable and not too expensive.

On the flip side, I have used [easyspace](http://blog.ajcw.com/2011/01/easyspace-easy-theft/) once and they were expensive, difficult to use and with extremely poor customer service.